# Can I use augmented reality?

Tags: windows-phone-7, augmented-reality

I'm developing a Windows Phone app.

I'm wondering if there is any way to user augmented reality with Windows Phone 7.

I read somewhere that we can use camera in our Windows Phone 7 developments.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

As of now, no it isn't possible. WP7 does not provide raw camera access, which would make it very difficult to do. The Mango Update will correct that.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, but not officially sanctioned - here's an article where a guy managed to hack it together using SLARToolkit: http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/12/23/wp7-camera-access-flashlight-augmented-reality-and-barcode-scanning/

Comment: Here's an update - using SLARToolkit with Mango: http://kodierer.blogspot.com/2011/05/augmented-mango-slartoolkit-for-windows.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's an OEM SDK that provides compass and camera access (see the LG Optimus AR application), but the standard developer offering is missing both of these APIs for now, so while it's possible, it requires access to privileged developer tools until the Mango update.